# Use TextWatcher to detect last text deleted

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I am having an `EditText` and have a `TextWatcher` for it.

I am entering number in it and I want to fill the field with 0 if the last text is deleted.

How can I do using the three methods of `TextWatcher`?

```
    input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            double value=Double.parseDouble(input.getText().toString());//here it will throw error if no text there. 
            //I do not only want to catch this exception and do something with it, but I want to detect this event and if it happens I want to try some solution to stop it.
        }
    });
```

Comment: check in ontextchanged if length of s is equal to 0 or if s is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in afterTextChanged method ... put if block to see is it empty or not. Also instead of using input editbox use Editable s which you are having in method parameter.

```
if (s.toString()!=null && s.toString().trim().equals("")==false){
   double value=Double.parseDouble(s.getText().toString());
}else{
   double value = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do like this:

```
 @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        try {
            double value=Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
            ... //if there is something to do with value
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            s.clear();
            s.insert(0, "0");
            // The method will be recalled since s was changed
        }
    }
```